# randomly select values those are not NA in R

Tags: r

How to randomly replace 15% of values those are not NAs in a data frame by NA values?
I need to know which values have been replaced. The positions must be stored in another matrix of booleans.

The difficulty for me is to replace only among values those are not already NAs.

EDIT :
Here is a sample :

```
NA 1 2 3 4
4 3 6 8 2
3 8 3 NA 7
```

I want to replace 15% of values those are not NAs (15% of 13, ie. 1 value).

Comment: A sample set would have helped

Answer (score 2):

I would convert data.frame to a matrix (to have access to the values as a vector), find 15% of the values and assign them the value of NA. I'll let you work out storing of replaced positions as an exercise. :)

```
del <- data.frame(w = runif(25), x = runif(25), y = runif(25), z = runif(25))
del <- as.matrix(del)
get.sample.index <- sample.int(n = length(del), size = 0.15 * length(del))
extract.del.vals <- del[get.sample.index] # these are the values that will be NA
del[get.sample.index] <- NA # assign those values NA
del <- as.data.frame(del)
```

Since we already have a data.frame with NAs, let's sample only values that are not NA. You will have to decide what 15% you want to sample, incuding NA or excluding.

```
# addendum
del <- as.matrix(del)
which.are.na <- which(is.na(del) == TRUE)
sample.index <- 1:length(del)
sample.index <- sample.index[-which.are.na] #exclude those that are NA
get.sample.index2 <- sample(x = sample.index, size = 0.15 * length(sample.index))
del[get.sample.index2] <- NA
del <- as.data.frame(del)
```

Comment: If you add:
`repl <- del # matrix to hold the replaced positions`
`repl[] <- FALSE # initialize with FALSE`
`repl[get.sample.index] <- TRUE # set all cells which have been replaced to TRUE`

you get a matrix repl of the same dimensions of del, where all cells are FALSE, and only the ones where del has been replaced with NA to TRUE

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I already have NAs in my matrix. The difficulty is to replace by NAs only 15% of values those are not already NAs.

Answer (score 1):

Since the sample data provided was a little too small to see what is going on, here's a better set:

```
n_data <- 200
some_data <- matrix(runif(200), nrow = 20)
some_data[sample(n_data, 100)] <- NA
some_data
```

Roman's method is fine, so this is merely a cleaner iteration of the code.

```
number_of_nas <- sum(is.na(some_data))
fifteen_pct_of_nas <- 0.15 * number_of_nas
na_positions <- which(is.na(some_data))
indicies_to_replace <- sample(na_positions, fifteen_pct_of_nas)
some_data[indicies_to_replace] <- 999
```

If you prefer the indicies of the replacement values in matrix form, use `arrayInd`.

```
arrayInd(indicies_to_replace, dim(some_data))
```

Comment: +1 for arrayInd. Looks like things are best hidden in plain sight.