# swap n percent of ones to zeros in R

Tags: r

I have a vector A which contains zeros and ones. I would like to randomly change n percent of the ones to zero. Is this the best way to do it in R (10% change):

```
for (i in 1:length(A)) 
{
    if(A[i] > 0)
    {
        if(runif(1) <= 0.1)
        {
            A[i] = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That code doesn't randomly change 10% of 1s. It changes a randomly distributed number of 1s.

Comment: Why not? If it encounters a one it generates a uniformly distributed number between [0 ... 1] and if this number is less equal 0.1 it changes the 1 to a zero. This occurs 1 out of 10 times on average.

Comment: possible duplicate of [randomly select values those are not NA in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323799/randomly-select-values-those-are-not-na-in-r)

Comment: @csetzkorn As you mentioned, you change 10% of values on **average**. However, this is different from randomly changing exactly 10%. For you, suppose you have ten ones. You could select exactly one value at random and change that to a zero, or you could do as you describe above.

Comment: Ok I got it - changing exactly 10% randomly selected rows with ones is much better anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without using the for loops and if statements:

```
##Generate some data
R> A = sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE)
##Generate n U(0,1) random numbers
##If any of the U's are less then 0.1
##Set the corresponding value in A to 0
R> A[runif(length(A)) < 0.1] = 0
```

The other point to note, is that you don't have to do anything special for values of A that actually equal 0, as the probability of change a 1 to a 0 is still 0.1.

As Hadley points out, your code doesn't randomly change 10% of 1's to 0. If that is really your intention, then:

```
##Select the rows in A equal to 1
R> rows_with_1 = (1:length(A))[A==1]
##Randomly select a % of these rows and set equal to zero
##Warning: there will likely be some rounding here
R> A[sample(rows_with_1, length(rows_with_1)*0.1)] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. This all looks great. Can you please explain why I do not swap 10% of my 1s to 0s in my original code? runif(1) gives me uniformly distributed number from [0 ... 1] doesn't it? That means that the second 'if construct' is entered 10% of the time on average ... in other words a one is swapped 10% of the time to a zero.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your A:

```
A <- round(rnorm(100, 0.5, 0.1))
```

This should do it:

```
n <- 10
A[sample(A[A==1], length(A[A==1])*n/100)] <- 0
```

where n is the percentage of your 1s that you want to change to 0s.

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize that:

```
A <- round(runif(20), 0)
A[sample(which(A == 1), 0.1 * length(A == 1))] <- 0
```

HTH

Comment: Worth noting that if `0.1 * length(A == 1)` is a non-integer, then `sample` will take the floor of that number.  It's not obvious from the question where or not @csetzkorn wants that behaviour, though it's only an issue for small datasets.